# Get macro name from a peeked token

Tags: expl3, latex3

I have a question concerning the decomposition of macro definitions:

In chapter XV, section 7 in the [interface3](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) manual is a list of possible decompositions:

For example, there is a command `\token_get_prefix_spec:N` listed in the interface3 manual. As described, it leaves the prefixes in the input-stream.

A token defined by `\cs_new_protected:Nn \someToken:n { do~something }` would thereby leave "\protected".

The other two, `\token_get_arg_spec:N` and `\token_get_replacement_spec:N`, leave the raw arguments or the replacement. All three of them work well with a `\l_peek_token` as "input".

But is there a method to leave the token name? The `\token_to_str:N` macro is not an option, as i want to know the (once expanded) name of a `\l_peek_token`: `\token_to_str:N \l_peek_token` just returns "\l_peek_token" and not "\someToken:n" (if the peeked at token is "\someToken:n").

Here is a small example showing what I want (compile with XeTeX):

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Nn \someToken:n {
    \peek_catcode:NF ## {
        char: #1\\      
        -~Meaning~of~next~token:~\token_to_meaning:N \l_peek_token\\
        -~Prefix~of~next~token:~\token_get_prefix_spec:N \l_peek_token\\
        -~Name~of~next~token:~\token_to_str:N \l_peek_token\\ % this is not working as wanted, I want \someToken:n !
    }
}

\newunicodechar{➀}{\someToken:n{a}}
\newunicodechar{➁}{\someToken:n{b}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
➁➀
…
\end{document}
```

(This question came up while I was searching for solutions for my other questions [Compare macro names instead of meaning](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397406/compare-macro-names-instead-of-meaning) and [Peek ahead and process characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/397250/peek-ahead-and-process-characters).)

Comment: That is not possible I guess, because `\l_peek_token` is just `\let` to the next token, i.e. it is assigned the same `\meaning` but the original “name” is lost.

Comment: @HenriMenke But how can `\token_to_meaning:N \l_peek_token` return the meaning (which includes the macro name: "\protected macro:->\someToken:n {a}") if it's lost? Could I somehow parse the meaning in such a way, that everything between ">" and "{" is "returned"?

Comment: That's not what's happening: ➁ is made active, and searches its next token; the next token is ➀, now that's the info you loose when you use peek functions, you no longer see the “➀” but have something like `\let\peektoken➀`; the info that's *inside* ➀ is what you now have, and inside it you have `\sometoken:n {a}`. It's not clear to me what you want to do with that?

Comment: I want to peek and remove the following token, if the token name of the "info inside" is `\someToken:n`. The use case is mentioned in the link below the source code: unicode replacement of composite-emoji (like flags or skin color variations). Other methods (also mentioned in my other questions/link below) don't work in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract the first token inside the definition of a macro (this needs to be an user defined macro and not a primitive, otherwise there might be situations in which it gives an error).

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Npn \fjs_string_first_delimit_q_nil:Nw #1 #2 \q_nil { \token_to_str:N #1 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fjs_sometoken:n
 {
  \peek_catcode:NF ##
   {
    char: ~ #1 \\      
    Meaning ~ of ~ next ~ token: ~ \token_to_meaning:N \l_peek_token \\
    \token_if_macro:NT \l_peek_token
     {
      First ~ token ~ inside ~ the ~ next ~ token: ~ 
     \exp_after:wN \fjs_string_first_delimit_q_nil:Nw \l_peek_token aaaaaaaaa \q_nil
     }
    \par
   }
}

\newunicodechar{➀}{\fjs_sometoken:n{a}}
\newunicodechar{➁}{\fjs_sometoken:n{b}}

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This is not entirely safe (e.g., `\def\foo{{}}` will cause problems if the next token is `\foo`), but for now this works well in your cases ➀➁.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like exactly what I was looking for. I'm trying to understand your code and have a few questions: What's the purpose of the "aaaaaaaaa"? It seems I can just delete it and nothing changes… What's the purpose of the `\q_nil`? I've read the section in interface3.pdf but can't make sense of it in your function `\fjs_string_first_delimit_q_nil:Nw`. In `\exp_after:wN` it's a placeholder to be not expanded, isn't it?!

Comment: Just in case the next token needs to grab arguments so that it doesn't fail and has 9 possible arguments to grab in the first expansion. This works with delimited arguments, it takes the first token and gobbles all the rest until `\q_nil`.

Answer (score 0):

@HenriMenke (unintentionally?) gave me the idea to parse a substring of the `\meaning` to check if `\l_peek_token` is "\someToken:n". With some explanations from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384179/136226) I got the following working code.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_my_tl
\seq_new:N \l_my_seq

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_once:nnNTF { nV }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \someToken:n {
    \peek_catcode:NF ## {
        char: #1\\      
        -~Meaning~of~next~token:~\token_to_meaning:N \l_peek_token\\
        \tl_set:Nx \l_my_tl { \token_to_meaning:N \l_peek_token }
        \regex_extract_once:nVNTF { macro:->\\someToken:n } \l_my_tl \l_my_seq { 
            -~Real~name~of~next~token:~\textbackslash someToken:n
        }{ 
            -~Real~name~of~next~token:~unknown
        }\\
    }
}

\newunicodechar{➀}{\someToken:n{a}}
\newunicodechar{➁}{\someToken:n{b}}
\begin{document}
➁➀
…
\end{document}
```

This solution seems like a hack. Unless someone tells me that there is no better solution, I can't mark this as an accepted answer :-(

Comment: "Real name of the next token" is ➀, `\sometoken:n {a}` is the meaning of that token.

Comment: @Manuel That's the point. I do not want the meaning, because it contains the parameter `{a}`. When I check for the meaning, ➁➀ would match, but ➀➁ wouldn't. But I want to match every kind of following `\someToken:n` regardless of the complete meaning. In that sense `\someToken:n` is the "Real name of the next token" and ➀ is only a symbol. My goals become more apparent in the linked questions at the end of this question.

Comment: It's not. May be the token that will end up eventually expanding after the current one, but in the same sense `\sometoken` will expand to `\peek_catcode` and `\peek_catcode` wil expand to something else. So, I do understand what you mean, and tried to answer that in the answer, but the real name of the next token is ➀ :P

Comment: You're right. But I'm just a self-tought amateur and not very fluent in the exact "vocabulary". Thanks for your answer :-)